# Vue.js life cycle to show a specific view at a time i want

Tags: web-applications, vuejs2, hook, lifecycle

I have a question about Vue.js and the topic is life cycle hooks.
I created a web app that is working with mobile/tablet and desktop.
the problem is that when I load the app on the desktop it works great but when I inspect it to see how the mobile is working I need to refresh the page to see that I'm on mobile and also refresh it every time I change between mobile modes: Vertical or Horizontal. all modes are works perfectly(only when I refresh the page) but I want the app know immediately what mode I'm in when I want to.
what should I do? is it about life cycle hooks? and if it does I would be really happy to know how can I do that!
thanks!

Comment: I assume you are rocking modes for development testing purposes and probably using Chrome dev tools.  You might consider the required refresh to be acceptable behavior since the issue only occurs for developers.   In real life when testing on a given device it will always know the mode when the page renders since a device doesn't actually change types.  If you really wanted the page to "sense" the mode change you might need to use a timer and check ever second or two, but I would not advise doing that. As it makes the code more complicated for the main stream use but only helps developers.